# Distance to city considering flood map - QGIS

Tags: distance, qgis

I am trying to calculate the distance from lakes to the city, considering flooded paths. My idea is  to compare the distance between flood and dry season. I have three shapefiles (1) lakes centroids (points - obtained from a polygon shapefile of the lakes), (2) flood map (polygons - obtained from a raster) , (3) cities (point). How can I use the flood to create a path through flood areas? Is there any way i can automatize that if the lake is disconnected, it adds the shortest distance to the a flooded path?

[Example of my shapefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsqkT.png)

I tried to convert the flood map (from the flood season) to lines  to use the network analysis but does not work because if returns disconnected boxes that won't calculate the distance. Any idea on how i could do that?